# How to segment with labelled data?

Tags: regression, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a historical dataset of target customers, of whom I know who has purchased the product. E.g. 100k target customers, of whom 10k purchased. I also have metadata Inc demographic information, and details about the product they bought.

I want to run segmentation closing to group together customer groups based on whether they purchased and what they purchased (e.g. high value Vs low value product).

What approach should I use? Not sure if I can use K Means if I include the labelled data of whether they bought or not? Or whether I can only run clustering on unlabeled data within only that customers who did buy the product?

Comment: What do you want to use the model for? What are you trying to find out? "whether they purchased and what they purchased" Sounds like you want either regression or classification. E. g., classify `x` into `$0-$5` or `$5-$10` or `$10-$15` etc. Or for `x` find `f(x)=$y`. What makes you want to use clustering? Why not just say, linear regression or something? BTW you already have your clusters, just take their mean and measure distance of a new customer from them.

Comment: Thanks for the question! I'll try to answer. I'm looking for a way to cluster a potential customer base. I have demographic data, and historic data. E.g. there's an elderly segment who but infrequently, and low value. There's 2x other demographic groups who but similar when they do but, but one is twice as likely to buy as the other... So I'm trying to work out if I can use that buying data in clustering, so that the data tells us there's a segment we need to market to differently. I've got lots of metadata, of which demographic is just one.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert non-numeric data to numerics, or some kind of categorical codes. Here's an example.

```
import pandas as pd
 
# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Year': 2020, 'Airport':2000, 'Casino':5000, 'Stadium':9000, 'Size':'Small'}, 
       {'Year': 2019, 'Airport':3000, 'Casino':4000, 'Stadium':12000, 'Size':'Medium'},
       {'Year': 2018, 'Airport':5000, 'Casino':9000, 'Stadium':10000, 'Size':'Medium'},
       {'Year': 2017, 'Airport':5000, 'Casino':10000, 'Stadium':15000, 'Size':'Large'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df = df.set_index(['Year'])
df

df_fin = pd.DataFrame({col: df[col].astype('category').cat.codes for col in df}, index=df.index)
df_fin
```

[image]